# Autocalculate value in Django formset field

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, formset

I'm using Django formset to allow user to enter stock details for the user in multiple rows at once.I have the price and quantity entered by the user in each row.i need to multiply this values and show in the last column for each row when user enter the value.
i tried to write the javascript as below which will work fine for first row.How can i make it apply for the entire table

```
function update() {
     document.getElementById("id_form-0-price").value = document.getElementById("id_form-0-quantity").value*document.getElementById("id_form-0-unitprice").value;
}
```

In the field name 'id_form-0-price' , 0 is the prefix set by formset,which is hardcoded in this case.i want to make the above script run for any row in the table.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure this is the answer you want.

```
function update(row) {
    document.getElementById(`id_form-${row}-price`).value = document.getElementById("id_form-${row}-quantity").value*document.getElementById("id_form-${row}-unitprice").value;
}
```

If this is the wrong answer, or you need additional code (dependent on how you're doing things), let me know in a comment and I'll be happy to update my answer.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what is required.however i could not get it working.is there a standard way to pass 'row' id parameter to the function above?

Comment: Depends. Can you give me some more code, such as where you call the update() function?

Comment: I have added an answer which just works fine.The call look likes this.

<td onkeyup="update(this);">{{ field }}</td>

Comment: It's impossible to know if that will work without seeing more of his code - more specifically, his HTML.

Comment: Lachlan,I myself added the working solution as the answer.it is working.but not sure it is the optimal one.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the below code.not sure whether it is an elegant solution.The row id which is generated by django formset starts with 0 while the row index of table starts with 1 i guess.

```
function update(x) {
idx = x.parentElement.rowIndex-1;
var el_qty='id_form-'+idx+'-quantity';
var el_price='id_form-'+idx+'-price';
var el_uprice='id_form-'+idx+'-unit_price';
document.getElementById(el_price).value = document.getElementById(el_qty).value*document.getElementById(el_uprice).value;}
```